# jQuery datepicker doesn't work in a page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use a jQuery datepicker (the one showed here https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default) in my page. But it really doesn't work! When I click on the textbox, any calendar is showed.

This is the code of my page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
</script>

  <title>Dashboard</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Timeline CSS -->
<link href="css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
  <link href="css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 </head>
<body>


  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <h1 class="page-header">Reports e stampe</h1>
              </div>
          </div>

        <form method="post" action="page1.php" target="_blank">
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/startmin.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must **include the shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: What is the error msg you've got?

Comment: that php tag was removed in an edit, the title should reflect that also

Comment: ok if this is indeed related to php; that will depend on how you're using this as; on a hosted site? local? if local as `http://localhost/` or straight in the browser `file:///`? question's too unclear. Define "doesn't work".

Comment: sorry it's the first time I write here! I'm a new at php... by the way, there's not relevance to php but what I mean is that this code is written into a php page. Should I delete the PHP tag from the post?

Comment: the tag was removed by someone else in an edit. the php in the title needs to be removed if it's not php-related, but if it is... see my comment above and/or the answer given below. Look at your developer console.

Comment: I don't get any error. The page runs on a server. With doesn't work I mean simply that the calendar under the textbook doesn't appear

Comment: that demo works, so you're doing something wrong. See Claudio's answer below. Again, look at your developer console; it tells all.

Comment: can you put your $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); within document onload and try.

Comment: Sorry i checked it now, in the console i got this error: $("#datepicker").datepicker is not  a function. (ln '$'("#datepicker").datepicker(),'$("date picker").datepicker' is undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're including jQuery twice (on header and at the bottom). That could defitively be the problem. First thing to try is to delete the last jQuery reference.

Next step would be a refactoring to move all scripts references and code to the very bottom of the page to improve page load performance but that's not strictly related to your problem, just an improvement.

**EDIT**

Now that we know the last reference was the problem I'll write how you should handle scripts on that particular page for [better performance](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html). Notice that I moved all script at the very bottom.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
  <link href="css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Timeline CSS -->
  <link href="css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
  <link href="css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 </head>
    <body>

    .... HTML CONTENT

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/startmin.js"></script>

    <script>
    $( function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked with just deleting the last jQuery reference